# How to check the value of a macro in C?

Tags: c

Basically I want to do the following:

```
#define TYPE float

int main()
{
  if (TYPE==float)...;
}
```

Of course it wont' work, and not sure how to achieve it.

Comment: I think GCC has a `typeof()` built-in that you might be able to use, but it isn't a good idea to write code as you look as if you're going to write it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the C preprocessor's *stringification* operator.

```
 #define xstr(s) str(s)
 #define str(s) #s

 if (strcmp(xstr(TYPE), "float") == 0) ...
```

For an explanation of this, see [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html)

Comment: Shouldn't that be `if(strcmp(xstr(TYPE)` ?

Comment: What part of the explanation on the linked site didn't you understand?

Answer (score 7):

If you're looking for a platform-independent mechanism, then there isn't one, basically.<sup>*</sup>

A feasible approach is something like this:

```
#if USE_FLOAT
#define TYPE float
#else
#define TYPE blah
#endif

...

int main() {
    if (USE_FLOAT) {
       ...
    }
}
```

However, as a general rule, you should avoid conditional compilation based on macros wherever possible.

---

<sub>* Well, it turns out there's @Barmar's slick solution, but I guess I'd argue that's a pretty heavyweight runtime check...</sub>

Comment: I'd use `#if USE_FLOAT` rather than `#ifdef` (to avoid fun times if USE_FLOAT = 0)

Comment: Might be better to say #ifdef USE_FLOAT in main as I have seen USE_FLOAT is sometimes defined without a value.

Comment: @DavidMokonBond: The thing with that is that it means you would have conditional compilation, i.e. a chunk of code that only hits the compiler some of the time.  And I have learned to hate that ;)

Comment: Why is the other method heavy handed? It'd just result in `if (strcmp("float", "float") == 0)`, which the compiler is likely to optimise out completely (including the `if`).

Comment: @teppic: If the compiler has `strcmp` as a primitive, then I agree there's a chance this will be optimized away at compile-time.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: I just tested it out of interest, on gcc it does remove the entire condition. That's pretty good.

Comment: @teppic: Yup, I just tested it too, and got the same result!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`__builtin_types_compatible_p()`](http://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~pad/tigcc/doc/html/gnuexts_SEC104___builtin_types_compatible_p.html) to tell if two types are compatible.

```
if (__builtin_types_compatible_p(TYPE, float)) ...;
```

This is supported by both GCC and Clang.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: What do you mean? It's supported by the GCC and Clang compilers at least (I don't know about other C compilers). That doesn't depend on platform.

Comment: Ah ok.  (By "platform" I really meant "compiler"...)